# Showing a page in a popup window if referer is outside my domain

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, popupwindow

I am using PHP for my page. I have a page, where the central part is an iframe, so when you click on an internal link, it showed there. Now, i have some file called communications.php, that will show on that iframe all the list of communications or eventually the communication itself using this kind of link: communications.php?idcommunication=22. I want to know if there is a way to open a popup window of th same page (I guess with JS)if someone try to reach the iframe from outside my domain (eg: from facebook). I also would like that  the same page in the popup, would not have some buttons or eventually change their destination.

for recognize if someone come from outside my domain, i found here this code:

```
    $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $refData = parse_url($ref);

     if($refData['host'] !== 'domain.com') {
     // here would end the php part i guess and start the part with JS that reload the same page
     //here will start the ne php part to close the if 
     exit;
     }
```

then would be great if on that popup (and only when the page is opened in form of popup, not "normal") can be added a button or link that can make the user going on the homepage of my website opening a new window and closing the popup. Eventually i am ready to listen alternative solutions  to show the full page to the visitors  clicking on the "idcomunicato" link, and not only its frame.

Thanks in advance for your kind suggestions.

Comment: You cannot reliably recognize where a visitor is coming from. However, if you can control the facebook link you could add an URL parameter indicating the origin of the link. You also cannot open a "popup" window from inside a webpage you don't control, which is what you seem to want to do.

Comment: Hi. Tthank You so much for your fast answer. What i want to do is go in my page called comments.php (with option "?idcomment=Myidnumber" and  if the page is opened from outside my website (not only from FB), resize it or reload it as a popup and in that case adding a link or edit a button destination link. I hope that i was clear this time. Sorry. English is not my main language.